# Find row containing specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet where every cell in column A is a date in sequential order.

```
    A    
----------
1/01/2016
...
12/31/2019
```

How can I return the row number of where a specific date is found?

Something like this:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

    today = Date

    row_today = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=today, _
        LookIn:=x1Values)

    MsgBox row_today

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the problem with the code you are using?

Comment: I get a run time errror, "Subscript out of range"

Comment: That error is from `LookIn:=x1Values` .  There is no such parameter. Try `xlValues`  There are other good practices outlined in your other answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is good practice to declare your variables at the start of your subroutine, in this case it would have helped you find the error. The other problem is that `.Find` is currently returning a range, where you would like to see the row number of that range. I'll explain how to solve both problems below:

---

## Declaring variables

In your code you want to return:

- `today` as a date and
- `row_today` as a long integer

*Edit: I previously recommended declaring row_today as `integer`. This will give errors if the row number is greater than 32,767; so I have amended to `long`, which can comfortably handle more than 2 million rows*

But you are currently returning:

- `today` as a Variant and
- `row_today` as a Variant

You can declare them like this:

```
Dim today As Date
Dim row_today As Long
```

---

## Using .Find

In this line of your code:

```
row_today = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=today, LookIn:=x1Values)
```

Firstly, you have a typo - it should be `LookIn:=xlValues` not `LookIn:=x1Values`

Secondly, you are returning the range of the cell that contains the date you are looking for. For more information on the `.Find` method, read the [MSDN Doc here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel).

To return the row number, you only need to add `.Row` at the end like this:

```
row_today = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=today, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

---

**So your final code should look something like this:**

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

Dim today As Date
Dim row_today As Long

today = Date
row_today = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=today, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

Debug.Print row_today

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! For both the solution and references, it's much appreciated.

Comment: This will likely return error for row number > 32,767, since that is the limit of the `Integer` data type.  Suggest declaring `row_today as Long`

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld I didn't know the limit was that small! I'll amend my answer.

Comment: I know this is old but your code where you say to add .row to the end has x1Values instead of xlValues.

Comment: Thanks @DanCue - 5 years after posting this, I haven't touched Excel in probably 3 years. I got an email notification of this comment and it made me laugh, so I fixed it up for you. Have a great day.

Comment: haha. Sorry to bother and thank you for providing something I was able to use.

Answer (score 1):

In a scenario where you don't find today's date the accepted answer will give you an error:
`.find` would return `nothing`, the added `.row` would then stop the code with an error.

Suggestion to change your code a bit to handle not finding anything:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

Dim today As Date
Dim row_today As Long

today = Date

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

    If .Find(What:=today, LookIn:=xlValues) is not Nothing then
        row_today = .Find(What:=today, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Today's date not found"
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
row_today = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=today, LookIn:=x1Values)
MsgBox row_today
```

with

```
set row_today = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=today, LookIn:=x1Values)
MsgBox row_today.value
```

Comment: OP wants to return row number, not the value of the range.